# apache: basic authentication before rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

I have an Apache in frontend that should redirect a request via a `RewriteRule`.

I have to put a basic authentication before the request is redirected, so I put this in the config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin xxxxxx
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName xxxxxxx
    RewriteEngine on
    ErrorLog logs/error.log
    CustomLog logs/access_log common

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Files"
        AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/tag.pwd
        Require valid-user
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1   [P,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** I would expect that all requests after authentication would be redirected with the rule `RewriteRule ^/(.*) xxxxxx:xxx/$1 [P,L]` but this doesn't happen. Apache search the page under `/var/www/html`

Comment: What did you expect to happen? What actually happened? What did you do to make it happen? What else did you try?

Comment: I would expect that all requests after authentication would be redirected with the rule
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1   [P,L]
but this doesn't happen
Apache search the page under /var/www/html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved putting the rewrite condition and rewrite rule outside the Locatio directive:

```
<Location />
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/tag.pwd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1   [P,L]
```

many thanks to h0tw1r3 for the suggestion

*Keep in mind that Location directives operate on URLs, and not directories. That means that if someone creates an alias to the document root, they'll completely bypass these authentication rules. (See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#location for more.)

Comment: "bypass these authentication rules" - Although, as noted in the docs, the single slash (`/`) is a "special case" as it applies to _every URL_ - so it can't be "bypassed" in this respect. (Of course, if an Alias is created from an entirely different VirtualHost then it will be _bypassed_ - but in this case, the entire VirtualHost is bypassed, not simply the `Location` block.)

Answer (score 13):

In general, Apache does the rewrite phase before the authorization phase, which is why your code performs the rewrite without ever asking for user to authenticate.

You can get around this with the `LA-U:REMOTE_USER` variable. Preface your RewriteRule with a condition which looks ahead ("LA") to the authorization phase:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1 [L]
```

See notes about this in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

As other posters point out, it's also better to take the RewriteRule directives out of the  block so they are more reliable.

Comment: This answers a _different_ problem to that stated in the question. "your code performs the rewrite without ever asking for user to authenticate" - That's not what is stated in the question. The OP states that the `RewriteRule` is not processed at all - the user _is_ prompted to authenticate. The code in the OP is missing a `RewriteEngine On` directive inside the `<Directory>` container and the regex is incorrect (there should not be a slash prefix in a _directory_ context) - both these issues will prevent the mod_rewrite directive doing anything. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62914796/369434

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Implicit directory rule ensures validation is always required before the rewrite is done.  Found that different combinations of apache modules changed the behavior, thus the accepted answer may not always work.

```
<Location />
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/tag.pwd
    Require valid-user
</Location>

<Directory /documentroot>
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
    RewriteRule (.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1   [P,L]
</Directory>
```

Comment: mmm it doesn't work :(. apache continue to search the page locally

Comment: Recently this came up again, even pyro's accepted answer failed to work for me on Apache 2.2.22 (Ubuntu).

Comment: You need to enable the rewrite engine (ie. `RewriteEngine On`) _inside_ the `<Directory>` container, otherwise the mod_rewrite directives will simply be ignored. (Which is _one_ of the problems in the OP.) See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62914796/369434) below.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <Directory /var/www/html/>
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthName "Restricted Files"
>     AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/tag.pwd
>     Require valid-user
>     RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1   [P,L]
> </Directory>
> ```

There are 2 issues here that will prevent your `RewriteRule` from doing anything:

1. You need to enable the rewrite engine *inside* the `<Directory>` container (a *directory* context). You've (incorrectly) enabled the rewrite engine in the outer `<VirtualHost>` container (a *virtualhost* context) - in which you don't have any mod_rewrite directives. The `<VirtualHost>` and `<Directory>` containers work in different *contexts*. If you don't enable the rewrite engine inside the `<Directory>` container then the directives will simply be ignored.

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   ```
2. When used in a *directory* context (`<Directory>` and `.htaccess`) the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, since the directory-prefix (that ends in a slash) has been removed. So, you need to remove the slash prefix from the regex, otherwise, it will simply never match in a *directory* context:

   ```
   RewriteRule (.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1 [P,L]
   ```

   (The `^` prefix on the *pattern* then becomes superfluous.)

#### Summary

Actioning the above points, this becomes:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/tag.pwd
    Require valid-user

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) http://xxxxxx:xxx/$1 [P,L]
</Directory>
```

---

**Alternatively,** you move the `RewriteRule` directive outside of the `<Directory>` container and use this directly inside the `<VirtualHost>` container in which you've already enabled the rewrite engine.

However, in this context, the mod_rewrite directives will execute *before* the authorisation directives inside the `<Directory>` container, so you will need the additional condition that checks the `REMOTE_USER` via a look-ahead (ie. `LA-U:REMOTE_USER`), as mentioned in the other answers.