# Password Protection with htaccess with Yii Framework

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I'm trying to protect my website with a username and password.

This is my .htaccess before adding the Password Protection

```
 RewriteEngine on

 # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # otherwise forward it to index.php
 RewriteRule . index.php
```

I have added the following code at the end of the file

```
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Password Protected Area"
 AuthUserFile .htpasswd
 Require valid-user
```

So my .htaccess is currently
     RewriteEngine on

```
 # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # otherwise forward it to index.php
 RewriteRule . index.php

 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "Password Protected Area"
 AuthUserFile .htpasswd
 Require valid-user
```

The password protection is working fine, but the website returns Internal Error 500

[image]

Why is the Password Protection cancels the RewriteEngine part? please advise.

Comment: It seems the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606435/apache-basic-authentication-before-rewrite.

Comment: I have tried to add the password protection between <Location /></Location>
 but it's not working @SiZE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the full-path for the ".htpasswd" to solve the issue

```
AuthUserFile "/home/folder/folder/.htpasswd"
```