# Perform basic authentication before rewrite on Apache

Tags: apache, basic-authentication

I'm trying to setup Apache as an authentication proxy to another server, basically authenticate and redirect if authentication is OK. I've created this entry in VirtualHost section in `http.conf`:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 <Location />
    Authtype Basic
    Authname "Credentials required"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
 </Location>

 RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
 RewriteRule "^/(.*)" https://otherserver.:443/site/$1  [R,L]
```

(I've looked into [apache: basic authentication before rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606435/apache-basic-authentication-before-rewrite) for this).
The problem is that authentication is checked against `/etc/httpd/conf/.htpasswd`, but whatever the result is, the condition matches because %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} contains the username.
Apache error file reports authentication failure but rewriterule is performed anyway.
I expected `%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER}` to hold remote user IF authentication succeeded (and empty on failure) not just the name entered by the user.
Am I doing something wrong? How to deal with that?
Thanks,
Jean

Answer (score 0):

answering to myself: worked this out using nginx which can do this in an easier easy way, for instance:
https://community.openhab.org/t/using-nginx-reverse-proxy-authentication-and-https/14542

Hope that helps,
Jean