# RewriteCond is not considered in default WordPress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Good morning,

I have a very strange issue with the default .htaccess with WordPress.

I have a "stats" folder in the webroot which contain something else than WordPress. Usually, I can access it by doing [www.example.com/stats/](http://www.example.com/stats/) on the web browser. But with one WordPress, [www.example.com/stats/](http://www.example.com/stats/) is rewrited to the index.php of WordPress.

Please note that I use the defaut WordPress .htaccess which is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Usually, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` should help to skip rewriting as `stats` is a directory. But `stats` still rewrite to `index.php`.

I already tried to add some other `RewriteCond` (with `REQUEST_FILENAME` and `QUERY_STRING`) to try skipping manually `stats` directory but it not works. Here are them (as requested on comments):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^stats$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^stats/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/stats/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !stats
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^stats/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/stats/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !stats(.*)
```

Both are not working.

As requested in comment also, I tried to rename `stats` to another name. And it works with the name `stats2`. But I still want to use `stats` as folder name.

Note that it is not a caching issue.

Inside the folder `stats`, there is a .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthUserFile /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats
require valid-user
```

Note that the folder `stats` is managed by ISPConfig.

Any idea to check? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“But it seems not working”_ - give us a proper problem description, including showing what _exactly_ you tried, in context of the already existing rewriting.

Comment: Could there be a previously created page called `stats` which could prevent you to access this directory? Did you try with another directory name?

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your suggestion. I just edited it for more precision.

Comment: _Show us_ what you tried, instead of just vaguely paraphrasing it.

Comment: Just tested renaming `stats` to `stats2`, the `RewriteCond` is working. So, what I should do to make it working with `stats`? I checked WordPress, there is no page/post published on www.example.com/stats

Comment: @CBroe just edited again the question.

Comment: Did you make sure you are not looking at a caching issue?

Comment: @arkascha no it is not a caching issue. I already checked this side.

Comment: Assuming that the `/stats` folder contains something like piwik... is there another distributed configuration file in there (".htaccess")? What does it contain? Maybe there is a loop here?

Comment: Everything is on the main post, there is nothing else in the .htaccess

Comment: To echo arkascha's comment above, do you have any other `.htaccess` files? ie. There is no `/stats/.htaccess` file? What is the format of your WordPress URLs? Where did you place those `RewriteCond` directives? Those `RewriteCond` directives don't really make sense in this context - they should _all_ be successful.

Comment: @MrWhite there is a .htaccess inside which protect "stats" with password. I just added the .htaccess into the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue!!!

> In general, Apache does the rewrite phase before the authorization phase, which is why your code performs the rewrite without ever asking for user to authenticate.
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13295036/7664726

I had to add it to the .htaccess in the website root:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
```

So my final .htaccess is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} !^$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks to add peoples in comment section helping me solve this issue.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? I think there is something more going on here... on Apache 2.4+ I would expect mod_authz to take priority? When requesting the `/stats/` subdirectory then the condition that checks `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` should already exclude the request. The question you link to deals with the main server config (not `.htaccess`). (The directives in the main server config do run _before_ `.htaccess`.) You shouldn't need the look-ahead here, ie. just `REMOTE_USER`, rather than `LA-U:REMOTE_USER`. I've added another answer that might be preferable.

Comment: I use Apache 2.4.25 (Debian 9)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the root `.htaccess` file, it may be preferable to simply disable the rewrite engine in the `/stats/.htaccess` file. Since mod_rewrite is not inherited (by default) this should prevent the WordPress front-controller in the root `.htaccess` file being processed.

For example, in `/stats/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine Off

AuthType Basic
: etc.
```

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't work. /stats/ still rewrite to index.php

Comment: Hhhmmm, that's weird! There must be something else going on here...